# What cable/adapter do I require to use DellU2715H as second monitor on a 2020 Retina iMac?

Tags: display, imac, displayport, video-adapter

I own this monitor https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00PRCRWRU / https://www.dell.com/lv/business/p/dell-u2715h/pd
It supports the following inputs:

- 2 HDMI(MHL) connector
- 1 Mini DisplayPort
- 1 DisplayPort (version 1.2)

Currently it is plugged into my Mac Mini 2012 using mini-displayport, but I am about to replace with an 27" 2020 iMac. My confusion is that formerly, DisplayPort and Thunderbolt were the same connector but Thunderbolt3 now uses the USB-C style connector. I want to make sure I have the right cable ordered in advance that will let me use this monitor at it's native 2560 x 1440  resolution and I am not sure what my options are, and whether I just need a single cable or some adapter.
There were some limitations on driving it at full resolution via HDMI, but I *think* that was a limitation on older Macs, not the monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI or DisplayPort cable should work.
Both USB-C and Thunderbolt 3 supports display output at the desired resolution.

For example [this cable](https://www.amazon.de/Adapterkabel-Thunderbolt-DisplayPort-Display-vergoldete/dp/B06XFG1YKT/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=usb-c%20auf%20displayport&qid=1627312721&sr=8-3) would work.